# Why configure Cordova config.xml if I already have a CSP in index.html

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap, content-security-policy

So I already have the following tag in my index.html:

```
content="base-uri *; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'sha256-LOml7W8v08pQhD4vcNTjNY+cvcYQV/kKF3Zhx8Ht2gc=' 'sha256-F9BbcOryafEGOcifHtySkTo4WqryjpUUKUEFIg2xMQ4='; style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self'; default-src 'none'; manifest-src 'self'; connect-src https://*.mywebsite.com ws://*.mywebsite.com wss://*.mywebsite.com https://api.mixpanel.com https://www.google-analytics.com; frame-src 'self' some.other.website; font-src 'self'; img-src *.mywebsite.com 'self' data: https:; media-src 'self' *.mywebsite.com">
```

which is already fairly strict.

We are now migrating to cordova. The questions are:

1. Since we already have a strict CSP in our index.html and cordova seems to be applying it correctly, do we need to do any configuration in the config.xml
2. If we do need to configure something in our config.xml, what should we configure given our CSP (Please note that we would like to allow our cordova app to redirect to any domain).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to configure anything in your `config.xml` unless you plan to show videos from streaming sites like YouTube.

In my `config.xml` I had to add this directly inside `<widget>`:

`<access origin="*" />`